# Formatting table with printf

Tags: java, arraylist, printf

I'm trying to output a formatted string using `printf`. The problem concerns a bank system. I have a ArrayList of type Transaction which contains the id, the amount of transaction, a string that determines whether it is a deposit or withdrawal, and the balance in the account.

First, the program prints the 4 columns, with no problem

`System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%s\n","Transaction","Withdrawal","Deposit", "Balance");`

I then try to iterate through the ArrayList and print out the information of each transaction. An if statement is used to determine which transaction is being done, and then I try to align the amount under the correct column depending on whether it was a deposit or withdrawal.

```
for(int i= 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
            if(d.get(i).type.equals("Deposit")) {
                System.out.printf("%-20d%-40d%-20d%d\n", d.get(i).id, d.get(i).amount, d.get(i).balance);
            }else {
                System.out.printf("%-20d%-20d%-40d%d\n", d.get(i).id, d.get(i).amount, d.get(i).balance);
            }
        }
```

It actually seems to print out the first line great:

```
Transaction         Withdrawal          Deposit             Balance
0                   7                                       1007
```

However, it then prints out a series of errors which I can't understand

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException:
>   Format specifier '%d' at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source) at
>   Account.printStatement(Account.java:87) at
>   Account.main(Account.java:43)

Any help with be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing one argument for the printf

Comment: For increased readability, use a for-each loop: `for (Transaction t : d)` and then use `t` instead of `d.get(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

This actually means that you have one %d with no corresponding value:

```
System.out.printf("%-20d%-40d%-20d%d\n", d.get(i).id, d.get(i).amount, d.get(i).balance);
```

You have 4 format specifiers and 3 values.

```
%-20d
%-40d
%-20d
%d
```

Values:

```
d.get(i).id
d.get(i).amount
d.get(i).balance
```

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz: Yes, the `if` `else` clause does also not make much sense as it is right now. The first `System.out.printf` should probably contain the deposit.

Comment: @badprogramming99: Happens to everybody. Something similar happened to me on Saturday.